# Breakout brick and paddle collision in Java

Tags: java, collision-detection, breakout

I'm working on a [Breakout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakout_(video_game)) game, and I'm having a brick collision problem. The ball bounces off the wall, oar and brick. However, when the ball touches the oar, the oar disappears, although I seem to have prescribed that the ball in this case should rebound. I'm really stuck on this one. How can I fix it?

```java
public class Breakout extends WindowProgram {
    /**
     * Width and height of application window in pixels
     */
    public static final int APPLICATION_WIDTH = 400;
    public static final int APPLICATION_HEIGHT = 600;

    /**
     * Dimensions of game board (usually the same)
     */
    private static final int WIDTH = APPLICATION_WIDTH;
    private static final int HEIGHT = APPLICATION_HEIGHT;

    /**
     * Dimensions of the paddle
     */
    private static final int PADDLE_WIDTH = 60;
    private static final int PADDLE_HEIGHT = 10;

    /**
     * Offset of the paddle up from the bottom
     */
    private static final int PADDLE_Y_OFFSET = 30;

    /**
     * Number of bricks per row
     */
    private static final int NBRICKS_PER_ROW = 10;

    /**
     * Number of rows of bricks
     */
    private static final int NBRICK_ROWS = 10;

    /**
     * Separation between bricks
     */
    private static final int BRICK_SEP = 4;

    /**
     * Width of a brick
     */
    private static final int BRICK_WIDTH =
            (WIDTH - (NBRICKS_PER_ROW - 1) * BRICK_SEP) / NBRICKS_PER_ROW;

    /**
     * Height of a brick
     */
    private static final int BRICK_HEIGHT = 8;

    /**
     * Radius of the ball in pixels
     */
    private static final int BALL_RADIUS = 10;
    private static final int DIAMETER = 2 * BALL_RADIUS;

    /**
     * Offset of the top brick row from the top
     */
    private static final int BRICK_Y_OFFSET = 70;

    /**
     * Number of turns
     */
    private static final int NTURNS = 3;
    private static final double DX = 1;

    RandomGenerator rgen = RandomGenerator.getInstance();

    private void moveBall(GOval o) {
        double vx;
        double vy = 1;
        vx = rgen.nextDouble(1.0, 3.0);
        if (rgen.nextBoolean(0.5))
            vx = -vx;
        while (o.getY() < HEIGHT) {
            if (ballAboveRoof(o) && vy < 0) {
                vy = -vy;
            }
            if (ballBehindWallR(o) && vx > 0) {
                vx = -vx;
            }
            if (ballBehindWallL(o) && vx < 0) {
                vx = -vx;
            }
            if (ballBelowFloor(o)) {
                GLabel l = new GLabel("GAME OVER");
                l.setColor(Color.RED);
                l.setFont("Verdana-30");
                l.setLocation(((getWidth() - l.getWidth()) / 2), ((getHeight() + l.getAscent()) / 2));
                add(l);
                break;
            }
            if (getCollidingObject(o) == paddle) {
                println("Paddle");
                vy = -vy;
            }

            if (getCollidingObject(o) != brick) {
                println("Brick");
                remove(getCollidingObject(o));

            }

            o.move(vx, vy);
            pause(10);
        }
    }

    GRect bricks;
    GRect brick;
    private GRect paddle;
    GOval o;

    //    GObject collider = getCollidingObject(o);
    private GObject getCollidingObject(GObject o) {
        double x = o.getX(), y = o.getY();
        if (getElementAt(x, y) != null) {
            return getElementAt(x, y);
        } else if (getElementAt(x, y + BALL_RADIUS * 2) != null) {
            return getElementAt(x, y + BALL_RADIUS * 2);
        } else if (getElementAt(x + BALL_RADIUS * 2, y + BALL_RADIUS * 2) != null) {
            return getElementAt(x + BALL_RADIUS * 2, y + BALL_RADIUS * 2);
        } else if (getElementAt(x + BALL_RADIUS * 2, y) != null) {
            return getElementAt(x + BALL_RADIUS * 2, y);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private boolean ballAboveRoof(GOval o) {
        return o.getY() <= 0;
    }

    private boolean ballBelowFloor(GOval o) {
        return o.getY() + o.getHeight() >= getHeight();
    }

    private boolean ballBehindWallL(GOval o) {
        return o.getX() <= 0;
    }

    private boolean ballBehindWallR(GOval o) {
        return o.getX() + o.getWidth() >= getWidth();
    }

    private GOval addBall() {
        int x = (getWidth() - DIAMETER) / 2;
        int y = (getHeight() - DIAMETER) / 2;
        GOval o = new GOval(x, y, DIAMETER, DIAMETER);
        o.setFilled(true);
        o.setFillColor(Color.BLACK);
        o.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        add(o);
        return o;
    }

    private void addPaddle() {
        paddle = new GRect((WIDTH - PADDLE_WIDTH) / 2.0, HEIGHT - PADDLE_Y_OFFSET, PADDLE_WIDTH, PADDLE_HEIGHT);
        paddle.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paddle.setFilled(true);
        paddle.setFillColor(Color.BLACK);
        add(paddle);
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        int newX = mouseEvent.getX();
        if (newX - (double) PADDLE_WIDTH / 2 >= 0 && newX + (double) PADDLE_WIDTH / 2 <= getWidth()) {
            paddle.setLocation(newX - (double) PADDLE_WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT - PADDLE_Y_OFFSET);
        }
    }

    private void addBricks() {
        for (int i = 0; i < NBRICK_ROWS; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < NBRICKS_PER_ROW; j++) {
                addBrick(i, j);
            }
        }
    }

    private void addBrick(int i, int j) {
        int x = BRICK_SEP / 2;
        int n1 = i < NBRICKS_PER_ROW ? 1 : 0;
        int n2 = j < NBRICK_ROWS ? 1 : 0;
        GRect brick = new GRect(x + i * (BRICK_WIDTH + (BRICK_SEP) * n1), BRICK_Y_OFFSET + j * (BRICK_HEIGHT + BRICK_SEP * n2), BRICK_WIDTH, BRICK_HEIGHT);
        brick.setFillColor(Color.BLACK);
        brick.setFilled(true);
        brick.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        add(brick);
    }

    // @Override
    public void run() {
        getMenuBar().setVisible(false);
        addMouseListeners();
        addPaddle();
        addBricks();
        o = addBall();
        moveBall(o);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code contains `getCollidingObject(o) != brick`. Should this be `getCollidingObject(o) == brick`?

Comment: I put it this way, but after that the program does not work at all and gives an error.